# Create new array with key from array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a new array by specify `key`

For example I have an array:

```
$data = [
    0 => 'name',
    1 => '29',
    2 => '7/26 City Avenue',
]
```

And I want to make new array like this

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'name',
    'age' => '29',
    'address' => '7/26 City Avenue',
]
```

How to make new array like above example ?

Comment: Have a look on [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Easy if thats all, but im suspecting its not https://3v4l.org/K7DpW

Comment: @SahilGulati Ahh `array_combine` is what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php
$keylabel=array("name","age","address");
$data=array("name","29","7/26 City Avenue");
$data_keylabel=array_combine($keylabel,$data);
print_r($data_keylabel);
?>
```

Comment: You just save my life haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


$data = [
    0 => 'name',
    1 => '29',
    2 => '7/26 City Avenue',
];

$data['name'] = $data[0];
unset($data[0]);
$data['age'] = $data[1];
unset($data[1]);
$data['address'] = $data[2];
unset($data[2]);

print_r($data);
```

This is an example. Your new array has the keys set in the way you want.

Comment: I can't use `unset` for my case but, anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Then just create a new array and pass the data there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest but NOT cleanesr solution would be parsing it into a new array like

```
$data_new = [];
$data_new['name'] = $data[0];
$data_new['age' = $data[1];
$data_new['address'] = $data[2];
```

Cleaner would be `array_combine`

Example from the reference [Link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-combine.php)

```
$a = array('gruen', 'rot', 'gelb');
$b = array('avokado', 'apfel', 'banane');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Output:
    Array
    (
        [gruen]  => avokado
        [rot]    => apfel
        [gelb]   => banane
    )

Hope that helps